# Mitigating Memory Dump and Analyze of an Application

Tags: android, memory, reverse-engineering

I have used Frida and Fridump for Memory Dump & Strings Dump on a mobile device which I installed an app for testing.

In the strings.txt file I have extracted using the mentioned above tools,
I'm able to find the session token of the application, passwords, and more sensitive information.

What is the correct mitigation for these kind of issues?

Comment: Restrict access to the device: physical access is root access and with root, you can do whatever you want.